# How to insert in MongoDB

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I'm doing CRUD in MongoDB. I tried this [example](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FireDAC.Phys.MongoDBWrapper.TMongoCollection) but I'm its not working. I'm getting *access violation* error then *stream read error*. Here is my code:

```
var
  fdCon : TFDConnection;
  fdMongQuery : TFDMongoQuery;
  mDoc : TMongoDocument;
begin
try

  fdCon := TFDConnection.Create(nil);
  fdMongQuery := TFDMongoQuery.Create(nil);
  try
    fdCon.Params.Clear;
    fdCon.Params.DriverID := 'Mongo';
    fdCon.Params.Add('Server=' + 'localhost');
    fdCon.Params.Add('Port=' + '27017');

    fdCon.Open;

    fdMongQuery.Close;
    fdMongQuery.FieldDefs.Clear;
    fdMongQuery.FormatOptions.StrsTrim2Len := True;
    fdMongQuery.Connection := fdCon;
    fdMongQuery.DatabaseName := 'HR';
    fdMongQuery.CollectionName := 'employee';

    mDoc :=
      TMongoDocument.Create(TMongoEnv(fdCon))
          .Add('name', 'ago')
          .Add('age', 12)
          .Add('address', 'PH')
          ;

    fdMongQuery.Collection.Insert(mDoc); // access violation > stream read error
    mDoc.Free;

  finally
    fdMongQuery.Free;
    fdCon.Free;
  end;

except
end;
end;
```

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This construction is wrong:

```
mDoc :=
  TMongoDocument.Create(TMongoEnv(fdCon))
    ...
  ;
```

You are type-casting the `TFDConnection` object to `TMongoEnv` when creating the `TMongoDocument` object, but that is an illegal type-cast (if you had used the `as` operator for the cast, it would have raised an `EInvalidCast` exception at runtime). `TMongoDocument` expects an actual `TMongoEnv` object.

You need to instead type-cast the `TFDConnection.CliObj` property to `TMongoConnection` after connecting to a MongoDB server, and then you can use the `TMongoConnection.Env` property to get the `TMongoEnv` object.  This is even explained in Embarcadero's documentation:

[FireDAC.Phys.MongoDBWrapper.TMongoEnv](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Phys.MongoDBWrapper.TMongoEnv)

> Do not [create](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Phys.MongoDBWrapper.TMongoEnv.Create) an instance of `TMongoEnv` directly. Instead, use the one from the [`Env`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Phys.MongoDBWrapper.TMongoObject.Env) property of a [MongoDB connection](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Phys.MongoDBWrapper.TMongoConnection).

[FireDAC.Phys.MongoDBWrapper.TMongoConnection](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Phys.MongoDBWrapper.TMongoConnection)

> To obtain an instance of `TMongoConnection`, do not [create](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Phys.MongoDBWrapper.TMongoConnection.Create) one directly. Instead, configure a [`TFDConnection`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDConnection) component to connect to your MongoDB server, ensure that it is [connected](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDConnection.Connected), and cast its [`CliObj`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDCustomConnection.CliObj) property to `TMongoConnection`

So, try this instead:

```
mDoc :=
  TMongoDocument.Create(TMongoConnection(fdCon.CliObj).Env)
    ...
  ;
```